# Workaround for lack of ConnectionSlow, Reconnecting and StateChanged events in SignalR Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm upgrading a project from SignalR to SignalR Core, and ran into the following issue. I don't see a way for the .NET client to quickly detect that it has been disconnected from the server. This happens when the web service recycles its application pool. It takes 90 seconds for the .NET Core client to detect that, via `HubConnection.Closed` event.

In the original SignalR, this was instantaneous via a number of events like `HubConnection.ConnectionSlow`, `HubConnection.Reconnecting` or `HubConnection.StateChanged`.

I don't see any of those events in latest stable SignalR Core release 1.0.1. I tried monitoring changes in `HubConnection.State` property, but that seems to mirror `HubConnection.Closed` event, and also takes 90 seconds to update.

What are the recommended workarounds to detect the change in connection faster?  Do I need to implement my own keep-alive messaging system?

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem turned out to be app_pool recycle operation taking 90 seconds to shut down old app_pool.  That meant the SignalR connection was truly alive during that time, which is why the clients couldn't not detect disconnection.  A quick workaround was changing the following setting from default 90 seconds to lower timeout (30 seconds in my case):

```
[application pool] > Right Click > Advanced Settings > Shutdown Time Limit (seconds) > 30
```